# Excel - return value from different row based on the value in the other row

Tags: excel

I have some table with string values that have duplicates. The first instance of each string is unique one and now I want to assign the value based on the value in unique one. Here is the example of my table and the results column is the one I want to achieve with a formula that work for the column that is not in any order.

```
String   Sequence   Unique  Value   Results
Address  1          1       Y       Y
email    1          1       N       N
Country  1          1       Y       Y
email    2                          N
Country  2                          Y
Country  3                          N
Country  4                          Y
Postcode 1          1       Y       Y
Postcode 2                          Y
```

You can see I am after populating Results for not unique ones with the value from the unique one.

Comment: Why is `Country` `3`  equal to `N`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why `Country` `3` is `N`. If that's a mistake and we assume the data is starting at cell `A1`, then the following in `E2:E10` should give you the results:

`=VLOOKUP(A2,A$2:D$10,4,FALSE)`